# Can IWebHostEnvironment be injected in a vbhtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables

I need to make a conditional for each environment. In another project (.cshtml) I could use

```
@inject IWebHostEnvironment Env

@if(Env.IsEnvironment("Development")){

}
```

My question is if I could do this on a vbhtml file? I didn't find any related like this.

Tried with System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Environment") but it's not the accurate one.

Comment: In order to use  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Environment")  do you have the value configured for Environment key in web.config?
<appSettings>
   <add key="Environment" value="Development" />
</appSettings>

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I search the values in the web.config and there're not present. For each environment it's another .config added i.e appName_DEV.config appName_STG.config. So now my question is: can I create a conditional with the name of those files or should I grab one unique config value from those files?

Comment: IWebHostEnvironment should have extension methods IsDevelopment(), IsStaging() and IsProduction(). So, you can call env.IsDevelopment() { //do something..} .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostenvironment?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that you can use those extensions, I could use it in another project. But the question is if you can inject IWebHostEnvironment on a vbhtml file since I couldn't do it. Beside this, I solve with another method  related with authentication.